# Implementing nested generic Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, nested, nested-generics

I have the following Classes / Interfaces:

```
// Model
public class A : IA { }
// ModelLogic
public class B : IB<A> { }

// Model Interface
public interface IA { }
// ModelLogic Interface
public interface IB<T> where T : IA { }
```

I try to create a new instance using the following code:

```
IB<IA> foo = new B();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'B' to 'IB<IA>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

**Can someone please explain why this is not possible?**

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) and [this blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) by Eric Lippert

Comment: B is an IB<A>, not an IB<IA>.

Answer (score 45):

OK, let's replace `A` with `Fish`, `IA` with `IAnimal`, `B` with `Aquarium`, and `IB<T>` with `IContainer<T>`. And we'll add a member to `IContainer<T>`, and a second implementation of `IAnimal`:

```
// Model
public class Fish : IAnimal { }
public class Tiger : IAnimal { }
// ModelLogic
public class Aquarium : IContainer<Fish> 
{ 
    public Fish Contents { get; set; }
}

// Model Interface
public interface IAnimal { }
// ModelLogic Interface
public interface IContainer<T> where T : IAnimal 
{ 
    T Contents { get; set; }
}

IContainer<IAnimal> foo = new Aquarium(); // Why is this illegal?
foo.Contents = new Tiger(); // Because this is legal!
```

You can put a Tiger into foo -- **foo is typed as a container that can contain any animal**. But you can only put a Fish into an Aquarium. Since the operations you can legally perform on an `Aquarium` are *different* than the operations you can perform on an `IContainer<IAnimal>`,  the types are not compatible.

The feature you want is called *generic interface covariance* and it *is* supported by C# 4, but you have to prove to the compiler that you will never put a tiger into your fish tank. What you want to do is:

```
// Model
public class A : IA { }
// ModelLogic
public class B : IB<A> { }

// Model Interface
public interface IA { }
// ModelLogic Interface
public interface IB<out T> where T : IA { }
```

Notice the covariance annotation on `IB`.  This `out` means that **`T` can only be used as an output**, not as an input.  If `T` is only an output then there is no way for someone to put a tiger into that fish tank because there is no "put into" property or method possible.

I wrote a number of blog articles while we were adding that feature to C#; if you are interested in the design considerations that went into the feature, see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/

Comment: Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'xx.IContainer<T>.Contents'. 'T' is covariant. I am getting this error. I am new to covariant stuff. What does the error mean?

Comment: @Sandeep: You are somehow using T in an input position when you have said that you are only going to use it in an output position. Is `Contents` a property with a setter? If it is then clearly T is being used in an input position, and therefore the interface cannot be made covariant in T.

Comment: Of all the variance-related questions on SO, this is by far the best answer that makes the most sense. +1

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code, just change

```
public interface IB<T> where T : IA { }
```

to

```
public interface IB<out T> where T : IA { }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to see when you have empty interfaces. Consider you have one method M in interface IB:

```
public interface IB<T> where T : IA 
{ 
    void M(T t); 
}
```

And here is implementation of B:

```
public class B : IB<A>
{
    public void M(A t)
    {
        // only object of type A accepted 
    }
}
```

Then you have object C, which also implements IA:

```
public class C : IA { }
```

So, if your code would be possible, then you could call:

```
IB<IA> foo = new B();
foo.M(new C());
```

Problem is that class B accepts only objects of type A. Error!