# Cannot convert from generic type to interface

Tags: c#, generics

I'm getting an error when trying to add generic object to a List<>.

Its probably related to  Covariance and Contravariance  but I not sure how to work around this. I've tried to restrict my generic types using *where T: IRegister*.

I have an interface to represent a register and then two classes which represent a ByteRegister and a DoubleWordRegister.

```
public interface IRegister
{
    string Name {get;set;}
}

 public class ByteRegister : IRegister
{
...
}

public class DoubleWordRegister : IRegister
{
...
}
```

I then have another class which represents a block of these registers all of the same type.

```
public class RegisterBlock<T> where T:IRegister
{
   private IList<T> _registers;

 ... constructors, properties etc

    public void AddRegister(T register)
    {
        _registers.Add(register);
    }
}
```

And finally I have a RegisterMap class which is used to define the list of register blocks and each register within the block.

```
public class RegisterMap
{
    private List<RegisterBlock<IRegister>> _blocks;

    public RegisterMap()
    {
        _blocks = new List<RegisterBlock<IRegister>>();

        RegisterBlock<ByteRegister> block1= new RegisterBlock<ByteRegister>("Block1", 0);
        block1.AddRegister(new ByteRegister("Reg1"));
        block1.AddRegister(new ByteRegister("Reg2"));
        _blocks.Add(block1);

        RegisterBlock<DoubleWordRegister> block2= new RegisterBlock<DoubleWordRegister>("Block2", 10);
        block2.AddRegister(new DoubleWordRegister("Reg3"));
        block2.AddRegister(new DoubleWordRegister("Reg4"));
        block2.AddRegister(new DoubleWordRegister("Reg5"));
         _blocks.Add(block2);
    }
}
```

**However I'm getting the following error:**

`Error  20  Argument '1': cannot convert from 'RegisterBlock<ByteRegister>' to 'RegisterBlock<IRegister>'` on the line _blocks.Add(block1) and similarly on _blocks.Add(block2);

Comment: What's your question?  The compiler error is pretty clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is indeed a [**variance problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).  You will need another interface for your `RegisterBlock` class, maybe `IRegisterBlock`:

```
public class RegisterBlock<T> : IRegisterBlock
    where T : IRegister
```

Then you can create a list of `IRegisterBlock`:

```
private List<IRegisterBlock> _blocks;
```

I actually had a similar situation in our code-base last week, and this is exactly how I resolved it.

Comment: Wow.. I never knew / ran into the **variance problem before today. I usually tend NOT to use IEnumerable.. but now I know exactly when to use it. Thanks.. I think I learned something really important today! My method was expecting a List<IItem> where List is contravariant, so using IEnumarable<IItem> makes perfect sense +1

Answer (score 12):

I notice that **you forgot to ask a question**. You merely stated a bunch of facts. I'm going to assume your question is "why does the compiler produce this error?"

The compiler produces that error because to not produce that error would lead to a crash at runtime. Suppose we allowed:

```
List<RegisterBlock<IRegister> _blocks = new List<RegisterBlock<IRegister>>();
RegisterBlock<ByteRegister> block1= new RegisterBlock<ByteRegister>();
_blocks.Add(block1);  // Illegal, but suppose it was legal.
```

Now what stops this?

```
RegisterBlock<IRegister> block1Again = _blocks[0];
```

Nothing. `_blocks` is a list of `RegisterBlock<IRegister>`, so of course `_blocks[0]` is of type `RegisterBlock<IRegister>`. But remember that of course the first item in the list is actually a `RegisterBlock<ByteRegister>`.

Now what stops this?

```
block1Again.AddRegister(new DoubleWordRegister())?
```

Nothing. `block1Again` is of type `RegisterBlock<IRegister>`, which has a method `AddRegister(IRegister)`, and `DoubleWordRegister` implements `IRegister`.

So you just put a double word register into a block that can only contain byte registers.

Clearly that is not safe. The only place where that can be made illegal at compile time is in the first step; the covariant conversion is not legal in the first place.

Incidentally, your question is often asked several times a day here. Twice so far this morning:

[Implementing nested generic Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352587/implementing-nested-generic-interfaces)

Answer (score 2):

Only interfaces can be covariant or contravariant in C#, so you can't explicitly mark your `RegisterBlock<>` covariant on `T` the way you want.

However, you don't really *need* covariance in this case, you just need to declare your two collection objects as:

```
RegisterBlock<IRegister> block1= new RegisterBlock<IRegister>
```

Since both `ByteRegister` and `DoubleWordRegister` implement `IRegister` you can add either of them to a `RegisterBlock<IRegister>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you did something like.

```
ByteRegisterBlock : RegisterBlock<ByteRegister>
```

This should get your code working, however, you do lose some flexibility.