# Variance in return type

Tags: c#, variance

**EDIT:**
Maybe this is a clearer, more to the point formulation of the question:

In some generic interface `IInterface<T>`, I want to return an object of a generic type, where one of the type arguments should be an implementation of `IInterface<T>`.

```
public class OtherType<T> {}
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    OtherType<IInterface<T>> Operation();
}
public class Impl : IInterface<int>
{
    public OtherType<IInterface<int>> Operation()
    {
        return new OtherType<Impl>();
    }
}
```

Since `Impl` implements `IInterface<int>`, it seems reasonable to me that I could use it this way. Yet, it seems I cannot, I get the compiler error

> Cannot convert expression type `OtherType<Impl>` to to return type `OtherType<IInterface<int>>`

Comment: Could you please convert your VERY long and confusing class names to something like A, B, C and so on?

Comment: @CarlPett: Have you been following Eric Lippert's excellent blog series on Monads? http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/21/monads-part-one/ It seems you are struggling to re-invent this construct, and could use some insight into the general mechanism.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I haven't, thanks for the tip! Seems really interesting. I only had time to read the first four parts yet, but so far I can't really see how to apply it here?

Comment: Removed context, which may have been quite a lot of noise.

Comment: Could you clarify "cannot"  Do you get an error, if so, which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot convert from generic type to interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353494/cannot-convert-from-generic-type-to-interface)

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Added the error, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `OtherType<T>` is a class and generic classes do not allow co/contravariance in C#. Generic `interfaces` do, as long as `out` types do not appear in any input positions, and `in` types do not appear in any output positions. In your code sample, you could get it to compile by introducing an additional interface marked covariant, and then altering your return type.

```
public interface IOtherType<out T> {} // new
public class OtherType<T> : IOtherType<T> { }

public interface IInterface<T>
{
    IOtherType<IInterface<T>> Operation(); // altered
}
public class Impl : IInterface<int>
{
    public IOtherType<IInterface<int>> Operation()
    {
        return new OtherType<Impl>();
    }
}
```

Whether or not this would actually fit your use case with your additional method definitions is something only you can know, given the limited about of detail in your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. Funny about the "limited detail" thing, though... My first formulation included the details about the exact types I'm using, and then I was bashed for having too much irrelevant context :P

Comment: Worked just as I wanted, perfect!

Answer (score 1):

`OtherType<IInterface<int>>` doesn't mean "implements" - it sort of means "is a type `OtherType` with a generic type parameter `Interface<int>`, but that isn't how you say it.

If you just want to make sure that the return type implements `IInterface<int>` then set that as the return type:

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    IInterface<T> Operation();
}

public class Impl : IInterface<int>
{
    public <IInterface<int>> Operation()
    {
        return new OtherType();
    }
}
```

where

```
public class OtherType : IInterface<int>
{}
```

This means you can return any type that implements `IInterface<int>`.

Otherwise you can make it a little more constrained on calling use a generic type constraint:

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    TRet Operation<TRet>() where TRet : IInterface<T>;
}

public class Impl : IInterface<int>
{
    public TRet Operation<TRet>() where TRet : IInterface<int>
    {
        return new OtherType();
    }
}
```

This means that you can constraint the operation to return a particular class, which has in turn to implement `IInterface<int>`.

It would be called:

```
Impl i = new Impl();
OtherType x = i.Operation<OtherType>();
```