# C# How to cast a generic type to interface it implements

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

This might be a silly question but I couldn't find a solution for it.

I have this structure (simplified for brevity):

```cs
namespace Test
{
    public interface IEntity
    { }

    public class BaseEntity : IEntity 
    { }

    public class OneEntity : BaseEntity
    { }

    public class Configuration<T> where T : IEntity 
    {

    }

    public class Service 
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Configuration<IEntity>> Configurations = new Dictionary<string, Configuration<IEntity>>();

        public void RegisterConfiguration(string name, Configuration<T> configuration) where T : IEntity
        {
            if(Configurations.ContainsKey(name))
                return;

            Configurations.Add(name, configuration); //Error: Unable to convert Configuration<T> to Configuration<IEntity>
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I cannot convert a generic type to an interface, but how can I achieve this? I could write `RegisterConfiguration` as:
`public void RegisterConfiguration(string name, Configuration<IEntity> configuration)`, but then it would fail when I call it with one of my entities (even if they all implement `IEntity`).

There must be something I did not understand properly with generics but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Just because two types, `T1` and `T2` exhibit a particular inheritance/implementation relationship, that *doesn't* mean that a single generic type parameterized by those two types (`G<T1>`, `G<T2>`) exhibits the *same* relationship. (With some exceptions for co- and contra- variance)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert from generic type to interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353494/cannot-convert-from-generic-type-to-interface)

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
public class Service<T> where T : IEntity
{
  public Dictionary<string, Configuration<T>> Configurations = new Dictionary<string, Configuration<T>>();

  public void RegisterConfiguration(string name, Configuration<T> configuration)
  {
    if (Configurations.ContainsKey(name))
      return;

    Configurations.Add(name, configuration);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will indeed work but it makes my Service "type dependant" and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work : Reason is you can cast from template to a interface but not reverse and also at class level it should know the template definition

```
public class Service<T>  where T : IEntity
{
    public Dictionary<string, Configuration<T>> Configurations = new Dictionary<string, Configuration<T>>();

    public void RegisterConfiguration(string name, Configuration<T> configuration) 
    {
        if (Configurations.ContainsKey(name))
            return;

        Configurations.Add(name, configuration); //Error: Unable to convert Configuration<T> to Configuration<IEntity>
    }
}
```