# VB.NET Fail to convert class to interface

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, interface

I have a simple piece of code as follows:

```
Public Interface ITest(Of T)
    Function getObj() As T
End Interface

Public Class clsTest(Of T As {IOrder, New})
    Implements ITest(Of T)
    Public Function getObj() As T Implements ITest(Of T).getObj
        Return New T
    End Function
End Class

Public Interface IOrder
    Property Name As String
End Interface

Public Class clsOrder
    Implements IOrder
    Public Property Name As String Implements IOrder.Name
End Class
```

When I create a clsTest object like:

```
Dim test As ITest(Of IOrder) = New clsTest(Of clsOrder)
```

I got the following error:

> 'ConsoleApplication1.clsTest(Of ConsoleApplication1.clsOrder)' cannot
>   be converted to 'ConsoleApplication1.ITest(Of
>   ConsoleApplication1.IOrder)'. Consider changing the 'T' in the
>   definition of 'Interface ITest(Of T)' to an Out type parameter, 'Out
>   T'.

Anyone knows the reason? If I do want declare the test as ITest(Of IOrder), how can I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make your interface covariant in `T` with the [`Out`-keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469539.aspx):

```
Public Interface ITest(Of Out T)
    Function getObj() As T
End Interface
```

Then this will compile:

```
Dim test As ITest(Of IOrder) = New clsTest(Of clsOrder)
```

E. Lippert can  explain it better than me:

- [Implementing nested generic Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352587/implementing-nested-generic-interfaces)